# Accepting null-values in a 'where in' constraint in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I want to filter on a specific field in my table, but also accept each record in which this field has value NULL. In other words:

- if value is NULL, add to results
- else: if value is in given list of values, add to results
- else: skip this record

Using the following constraint, the NULL-records are excluded from the result set:

$q->andWhereIn('rec.rec_loc_id', $permissions['locations']['ids']);

I've thought about adding another condition orWhere() with 'IS NULL', but due to other (conditional) where-constraints within the same query, this would become way too complex.

Answer (score 0):

My own solution, although I still think there should be a better way to achieve the desired result:

`$q->andWhereIn('IFNULL(rec.rec_loc_id, 0)', array_merge(array(0),$permissions['locations']['ids']));`